KMP Build using WKWebView is `missing entitlements`
I'm using Kotlin Multiplatform to generate a WebView in my iosMain implementation:
@Composable
actual fun LoadUrl(url: String) {
  val webView = remember { WKWebView() }
  UIKitView(
    factory = {
      webView.apply {
        WKWebViewConfiguration().apply {
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
          allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
          allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
        }
        loadRequest(NSURLRequest(NSURL(string = url)))
      }
      webView
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
  )
}

Unfortunately, it fails to load.  My understanding is that no additional entitlements are required, but the error says otherwise:
2024-10-04 23:29:07.074826-0400 iosApp[7557:140326] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "((target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.rendering AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.networking AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.webcontent))" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=((target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.rendering AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.networking AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.webcontent))}>

I have tried adding the entitlements to my iosApp.entitlements file, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.  All the research online tells me that I shouldn't even have to add entitlements to run this.
SOLVED:

Do not embed a WebView in a LazyList
[Only if you're using http instead of https] Put the App Transport Security Settings settings in your Info.plist file, not anywhere else.


What url are you having trouble with? "https://google.com" seems to work fine to me. You are also missing .fillMaxSize() or some other sizing modifier, without it the view will have zero size.

Any URL.  I've tried https://google.com and http://google.com too.  I applied the .fillMaxSize() modifier, but it is still throwing the same entitlement error and showing nothing.

try to add NSAppTransportSecurity into your Info.plist
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>


I have made that change.  It did not affect the error, even after cleaning the build folders in Xcode and Android Studio.  I also invalidated caches.  No joy.

I am using Xcode 16, Android Studio Koala, and K2 compiler.  Not sure if that changes anything

It turns out, these fields were added to my Custom IOS Target Properties instead of a separate Info.plist file.  Switching to a plist file solved the issue.

Another issue is that WebViews do not work in LazyLists

@RobertJamison this setting should only be needed for HTTP requests, app should work fine with HTTPS. allowing arbitrary loads makes your app vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks and other security issues. Apple recommends using HTTPS wherever possible. If you must allow HTTP for specific domains, a more secure approach is to use domain-specific exceptions rather than allowing arbitrary loads globally.

@PhilDukhov thanks!  I will re-evaluate the risk of leaving that setting enabled
